# Clearing checkboxes in a checkedboxlist in powershell studio

Tags: powershell, checkboxlist

I have a giant checkedboxlist that I have created that I need a button to clear all of the checked items with. Here is what I have:

```
 $btnResetGroups_Click = {
    foreach ($chkbox in $chklistGroups)
    {
        $chkbox.ClearSelected() # I tried to do $chkbox.Checked = $false but it doesn't recognize 'checked' as a property
    }

    #   $chklistGroups.ClearSelected()
}
```

Is there a reason why this doesn't work?

**EDIT:** This is the code that populates the checkboxlist:

```
$formPTINewUserCreation_Load={
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    # read in the XML files
    [xml]$NewUserXML = Get-Content -LiteralPath \\papertransport.com\files\UserDocuments\mneis\Code\XML\NewUserTest.xml

    # popoulate the checklist with the groups from active directory
    $AD_ResourceGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Resource Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Paper Transport,DC=papertransport,DC=com"
    $AD_ResourceGroups | ForEach-Object { $chklistGroups.Items.Add($_.name) }
}
```

[image: This is the GUI itself:]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$chkbox.Checked = $false` ? Since `$chkbox` is the object you want to change

Comment: Realized that was a mistake when I posted it. I have since changed it and it still does not work. When I type `$chkbox`, it doesn't recognize checked as a property of `$chkbox`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: The next thing to check would be to make sure that `$chklistGroups` has the right things in it. If it isn't being populated correctly then that could cause this issue

Comment: If it is being populated correctly, then I would go ahead and type in each checkbox's name and do `checkbox.Checked = $false`. I haven't personally ever used a foreach loop to uncheck checkboxes, but in theory it should still work

Comment: I was actually hoping there was a way to do it without using a foreach. You would think that there would be a way to just clear the entire thing without having to loop through every single item in the list, especially since this list is easily 300+ items.

Comment: That's a downside of using PowerShell to make GUIs.. It's supposed to do the opposite so that you don't need a GUI (: +1 for the good question

Comment: [`$chklistGroups.ClearSelected()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.clearselected(v=vs.110).aspx) might do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that every checkbox is unchecked when the button is clicked the code must loop through the container holding the Checkboxes.

```
$btnResetGroups_Click = {
    # get the container (in this case it looks like a list box)
    $myCheckBoxes = $myListBox.Items
    # next loop through each checkbox in the array of checkbox objects
    foreach ($chkbox in $myCheckBoxes)
    {
        $chkbox.Checked = $false
    }
}
```

This will ensure that every checkbox in the container is set to false. From the style of the GUI I'm assuming this is WPF and not Winforms.

Comment: +1 I agree with @Jason Snell. Doing it the way you posted it originally @Matt it will not work, but Jason's is definitely correct as long as your `$chklistGroups` is being populated correctly

Comment: That's what boggles my mind, as this should work. My `$chklistGroups` does indeed populate correctly, which is why i'm confused as to why I'm having so much trouble clearing all of this.

Comment: How are you populating your `$chklistGroups`?

Comment: @Matt Might be a scoping issue, try `foreach($chkbox in $script:chklistGroups)`. What version of PowerShell and the CLR are you running (`$PSVersionTable`)?

Comment: I am running 5.1.14393.1480 for the powershell version and CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: @JasonSnell the list is populated with the resource groups from active directory. I'll update the original post with the code that populates it.

Comment: So looking at your code it basically looks like you're not even touching the checkboxes. You are populating an array with strings from Active Directory and then attempting to use that array as a list of checkboxes. You have to actually work off an array of checkbox arrays.

Comment: Is your GUI built in Winforms or WPF? If winforms you can loop through the Main Form Controls and check each control type and then clear every check box. If it's WPF you can do something similar with the Main Window.

Comment: So what you're saying is that they're not actually checkboxes?

Comment: @JasonSnell It's actually being built with Powershell Studio 2017.

Comment: Not the application that's building it but the underlying code. Winforms is an older GUI format and WPF is a newer GUI format that .NET uses. Your code `$AD_ResourceGroups | ForEach-Object { $chklistGroups.Items.Add($_.name) }` is not adding checkboxes to `$chklistGroups`. All it's doing is adding string.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$DataCheckbox.Add_click({
    
        $BoxState = $DataCheckbox.CheckState
        
        if($BoxState -eq $false)
        {
          $DataCheckbox.Checked = $false
        }
        else
        {
          $DataCheckbox.Checked = $true
        }
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).